# Property quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-file not working with unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, ssl, quarkus

My Quarkus application has to connect to some HTTPS resources for which I have to use a custom keystore.

I've followed this guide to configure SSL using a custom jks: https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference#supporting-secure-connections-with-ssl

Thus I added two properties to my application, with the keystore filesystem location and its password:

```
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-file=/tmp/quarkus/keystore.jks
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-password=mypassword
```

On startup I see this exception:

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:276)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:623)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 38 more

2020-03-20 10:39:04,089 INFO  [io.qua.dev] (vert.x-worker-thread-1) Hot replace total time: 0.372s
```

If I launch the application with ssl debug (`./mvnw clean compile quarkus:dev -Djavax.net.debug=all`) I can see no mention of my keystore (only the cacerts of the JDK):

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2020-03-20 10:38:13.910 CET|TrustStoreManager.java:161|Inaccessible trust store: /Users/myuser/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.6.hs-adpt/lib/security/jssecacerts
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2020-03-20 10:38:13.911 CET|TrustStoreManager.java:112|trustStore is: /Users/myuser/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.6.hs-adpt/lib/security/cacerts
trustStore type is: pkcs12
trustStore provider is: 
the last modified time is: Wed Jan 15 13:06:55 CET 2020
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2020-03-20 10:38:13.911 CET|TrustStoreManager.java:311|Reload the trust store
```

However if I start it using the usual truststore JVM params I can see it and the application works:

```
./mvnw clean compile quarkus:dev -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Users/myuser/development/keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=mypassword  -Djavax.net.debug=all
```

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2020-03-20 10:49:08.812 CET|TrustStoreManager.java:112|trustStore is: /tmp/quarkus/keystore.jks
trustStore type is: pkcs12
trustStore provider is: 
the last modified time is: Fri Mar 20 10:07:16 CET 2020
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2020-03-20 10:49:08.812 CET|TrustStoreManager.java:311|Reload the trust store
```

However I would like it to work with the `quarkus.http.ssl.certificate` params.

Could this be a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this problem correctly, your Quarkus app is a client which connects to some server using HTTPS.

Ehat you really need in this case is to provide the certificate which is used to validate the server that your application tries to connect to. This is why it works when you provided a truststore using javax.net.ssl.* parameters.

The guide you mentioned in Quarkus documentation is about exposing a server with SSL. Thus, in this case you need to provide a keystore. I don't know if Quarkus itself supports providing the truststore using specific properties. However, depending on the way your application connects to the HTTPS server, you may try to configure it there.